# PowerShell comparing two DataTables - issue with filter on two columns

Tags: powershell, datatable

Issue: When I try compare two data tables against two columns (show where column A=column A, column B is not present), I can't seem to get a match.

[Sample data below]

How can I match [only the groups that both tables have in common] and show [who is missing from the matched groups]?  When I try, I can only show who is missing from any of the groups (aka Charlie).  I also need Bob to appear in group B.

To reproduce the issue - run this snippet in PowerShell:

```
## Live data table
# create "live" data:
$dtLive = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$dtLive.Columns.Add("GroupEmailAddress") 
$dtLive.Columns.Add("MemberEmailAddress")

# add Alex to both groups, add Bob to just A-Group
$row = $dtLive.NewRow()
$row.GroupEmailAddress = "A-Group@company.com"
$row.MemberEmailAddress = "alex@company.com"
$dtLive.Rows.Add($Row)

$row = $dtLive.NewRow()
$row.GroupEmailAddress = "B-Group@company.com"
$row.MemberEmailAddress = "alex@company.com"
$dtLive.Rows.Add($Row)

$row = $dtLive.NewRow()
$row.GroupEmailAddress = "A-Group@company.com"
$row.MemberEmailAddress = "bob@company.com"
$dtLive.Rows.Add($Row)

## Updated data table
# mimic existing "live" data:
$dtUpdated = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$dtUpdated.Columns.Add("GroupEmailAddress") 
$dtUpdated.Columns.Add("MemberEmailAddress")

# add Alex to both groups, add Bob to just A-Group
$row = $dtUpdated.NewRow()
$row.GroupEmailAddress = "A-Group@company.com"
$row.MemberEmailAddress = "alex@company.com"
$dtUpdated.Rows.Add($Row)

$row = $dtUpdated.NewRow()
$row.GroupEmailAddress = "B-Group@company.com"
$row.MemberEmailAddress = "alex@company.com"
$dtUpdated.Rows.Add($Row)

$row = $dtUpdated.NewRow()
$row.GroupEmailAddress = "A-Group@company.com"
$row.MemberEmailAddress = "bob@company.com"
$dtUpdated.Rows.Add($Row)

## NOW THE ACTUAL UPDATES
# add Bob to A-Group
$row = $dtUpdated.NewRow()
$row.GroupEmailAddress = "B-Group@company.com"
$row.MemberEmailAddress = "bob@company.com"
$dtUpdated.Rows.Add($Row)

# add new person Charlie to A-Group
$row = $dtUpdated.NewRow()
$row.GroupEmailAddress = "A-Group@company.com"
$row.MemberEmailAddress = "charlie@company.com"
$dtUpdated.Rows.Add($Row)

# add new person Dan to (new) C-Group
$row = $dtUpdated.NewRow()
$row.GroupEmailAddress = "C-Group@company.com"
$row.MemberEmailAddress = "dan@company.com"
$dtUpdated.Rows.Add($Row)
```

This snippet shows any entries that share the same group names:

`$dtUpdated | Where-Object {($_.GroupEmailAddress -in $dtLive.GroupEmailAddress)}`

results:

```
GroupEmailAddress   MemberEmailAddress
-----------------   ------------------
A-Group@company.com alex@company.com
B-Group@company.com alex@company.com
A-Group@company.com bob@company.com
B-Group@company.com bob@company.com
A-Group@company.com charlie@company.com
```

This snippet shows ONLY Member email addresses that are missing in the LIVE data table (irrespective of group membership):

`$dtUpdated | Where-Object {($_.MemberEmailAddress -notin $dtLive.MemberEmailAddress)}`

result:

```
GroupEmailAddress   MemberEmailAddress
-----------------   ------------------
A-Group@company.com charlie@company.com
C-Group@company.com dan@company.com
```

Since I want to match on groups for what is missing, we don't want Dan (group C is not in the live table).  We want Charlie (group A) and Bob (group B)

If I run something like this:

`$dtUpdated | Where-Object {($_.GroupEmailAddress -in $dtLive.GroupEmailAddress) -and ($_.MemberEmailAddress -notin $dtLive.MemberEmailAddress)}`

or

`$dtUpdated | Where-Object {($_.GroupEmailAddress -in $dtLive.GroupEmailAddress)} | Where-Object {($_.MemberEmailAddress -notin $dtLive.MemberEmailAddress)}`

I end up filtering to just Charlie (new to any group).  How do I include that Bob in group B is missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: Basically the premise would be to add those missing rows to `$dtLive` right?

Comment: yes - we just want to add to the live if it's missing. thanks!

Comment: Apparently you want to do a **FullJoin**. For a complete reusable solution which is probably faster as it  uses a hashtable, you might try this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `$dtLive |FullJoin $dtUpdated -On GroupEmailAddress, MemberEmailAddress`

Comment: interesting take @iRon - thanks for the module suggestion - I can definitely put that to use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly this should work, basically the **new rows added to `$dtLive` using the examples tables would be**:

```
B-Group@company.com -> bob@company.com
A-Group@company.com -> charlie@company.com
C-Group@company.com -> dan@company.com
```

The code would be:

```
$map = $dtLive.Rows | Group-Object GroupEmailAddress -AsHashTable -AsString
foreach($row in $dtUpdated.Rows) {
    # if this `GroupEmailAddress` doesn't exist in `$dtLive`
    if($row.GroupEmailAddress -notin $dtLive.GroupEmailAddress) {
        $dtLive.ImportRow($row)
        continue
    }
    # if this `MemberEmailAddress` doesn't exist in the Group Of `GroupEmailAddress`
    if($row.MemberEmailAddress -notin $map[$row.GroupEmailAddress].MemberEmailAddress) {
        $dtLive.ImportRow($row)
    }
}
```

And the final output when inspecting `$dtLive`:

```
GroupEmailAddress   MemberEmailAddress
-----------------   ------------------
A-Group@company.com alex@company.com
B-Group@company.com alex@company.com
A-Group@company.com bob@company.com
B-Group@company.com bob@company.com
A-Group@company.com charlie@company.com
C-Group@company.com dan@company.com
```

Comment: Oh my gosh - that's AWESOME.  I don't need to add 'Dan' per my original scope (only looking at missing members of groups that match), but that's irrelevant:  That hashtable method is what I need to do the full compare cleanly.  This is a great answer and will help me in future work.  Thanks so much!

Comment: #liveSaver... :D